# Почему не добавляется иконка font awesome 5 через css псевдоэлементу?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Почему не добавляется иконка font awesome 5 через css псевдоэлементу?

Вот код:

```
.header__offer::before {
    content: "\f104";
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Comment: `font-weight` нужен, кода то тоже мучился, когда на пятерку перешел.

Answer (score 1):

Если вызвать иконку Font Awesome 5 через тег `i` и потом посмотреть код `::before` то можно найти еще очень много параметров css. В общем, если добавить нижеследующие параметры то все будет работать:

```
font-family: Font Awesome\ 5 Free;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
display: inline-block;
font-style: normal;
font-variant: normal;
text-rendering: auto;
line-height: 1;
font-weight: 900;
```

Answer (score 0):

Если иконки не отображаются, то попробуйте ознакомится с данной статьей :

[Проблемы с отображением fontAwesome иконок](https://www.templatemonster.com/help/ru/font-awesome-icons-dont-show.html)

```css
.header__offer{
  position: relative;
}
.header__offer > p{
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.header__offer::before {
    content: "\f104";
    font-family: Font Awesome\ 5 Free;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-5sAR7xN1Nv6T6+dT2mhtzEpVJvfS3NScPQTrOxhwjIuvcA67KV2R5Jz6kr4abQsz" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="header__offer">
  <p>fasdfasd<p>
</div>
```

Comment: Иконка не сработала

Comment: @Артур что значит не сработала? Вы подключили вообще fontawesome? и как вы его подключили?

Comment: @Артур в примере, нажав **выполнить код** все работает

Comment: Нет, я посмотрел, отображается поломанная иконка, значит она не отобразилась, там должна быть стрелка. Проверьте сами

Comment: https://ibb.co/bA7T80 - прошу, как это выглядит у меня

Comment: Я не могу перейти по ссылке, но иконка даже здесь не отображается, font awesome подключил правильно

Comment: @Артур возможно это связано с вашим браузером, я с такими вещами лично не сталкивался, попробуйте открыть другой браузер, например firefox или safari - проверьте там, если не поможет, то будем разбираться дальше

Comment: Скажите, а вообще иконки у вас нормально работают??

Comment: Да вроде работали нормально

Comment: @Артур добавил в ответ статью, прошу ознакомьтесь, я думаю, должна помочь

Comment: Я даже локальную версию скачал, все равно не отображаются

Comment: @Артур тут проблема явно не в том как вы подключаете, так как вы не видите это в примере.

Comment: Попробую установить через @font face

Comment: Ну да, мне тоже это кажется странным

Comment: @Артур я изменил `font-family` -  попробуйте сейчас

Comment: Все равно не отобразилась, но спасибо за помощь, я нашел решение, я скачал font awesome на компьютер и подключил иконки через @font face, теперь буду только так подключать, так они вроде отображаютя без помех

Comment: То что Вы скачали это конечно хорошо, но проблему Вы не решили совсем) Это проблема с glyphs для unicode, которые у каждой системы свои. Когда устанавливается какой либо шрифт оффлайн, список поддерживаемых glyphs расширяется, и Вы начинаете видеть их на своей машине, но это только решение для Вас

Answer (score 0):

```css
.header__offer{
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  display: inline-block;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-rendering: auto;
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: 900;
}
.header__offer::before {
    content: "\f104";
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-5sAR7xN1Nv6T6+dT2mhtzEpVJvfS3NScPQTrOxhwjIuvcA67KV2R5Jz6kr4abQsz" crossorigin="anonymous">

Custom:
<div class="header__offer"></div>
<br/>
Font Awesome:
<i class="fas fa-angle-left"></i>
```

Чтобы использовать FA кастомно через css нужно делать примерно так как показано выше.

Проблема заключается в том что `font-weight` не был указан как `900`, следовательно не испоьзовался шрифт *Font Awesome 5 Free* **Solid** и что значит что glyphs для него не были загружены, поэтому и отображался "тофу"-символ (это такой термин, да), потому что в Вашей системе нет глифа для Юникод символа `\f104`.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте добавить свойство display. По своему опыту помню, что необходимо для before/after задавать content и display, иначе трудно предсказать как будет выглядеть. Подробнее про это можете почитать вот тут: http://htmlbook.ru/css/before

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Дополнил, спасибо